# How to set the positions of one thead elements to another thead element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi everybody I'm trying to set the position of the first table as the position in the second table.
The first table is visible before scroll, and after scroll the second table changes from invisible to visible, but the position of the elements is different.

Jquery: function `init()` when page load, I get the first table and get in an array all the positions and clone to another table and delete tbody of the cloned table.

```js
    $.fn.fixMe = function () {
        var posiciones = [];
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                    $t_fixed;
            function init() {
                
                posiciones[0] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(1)").position();
                posiciones[1] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(2)").position();
                posiciones[2] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(3)").position();
                posiciones[3] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(4)").position();
                posiciones[4] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(5)").position();
                posiciones[5] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(6)").position();
                posiciones[6] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(7)").position();
                posiciones[7] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(8)").position();
                posiciones[8] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(9)").position();
                posiciones[9] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(10)").position();
                posiciones[10] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(11)").position();
                posiciones[11] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(12)").position();
                posiciones[12] = $(".blue thead tr :nth-child(13)").position();
                
                
                $this.wrap('<div class="container2" class="table table-hover"/>');
                $t_fixed = $this.clone();
                $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
               
                resizeFixed();
                console.log(posiciones);
            }
            function resizeFixed() {
                $t_fixed.find("th").each(function (index) {
                    $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
                });
            }
            function scrollFixed() {
                
                var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
                        tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
                        tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
                if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom) {
                    $t_fixed.hide();
                    
                    console.log("no anclado");
                    console.log($("thead tr :nth-child(1)").position());
                    
                    
                } else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden")) {
    
                    $t_fixed.show();
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(1)").css({'left':posiciones[0].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(2)").css({'left':posiciones[1].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(3)").css({'left':posiciones[2].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(4)").css({'left':posiciones[3].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(5)").css({'left':posiciones[4].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(6)").css({'left':posiciones[5].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(7)").css({'left':posiciones[6].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(8)").css({'left':posiciones[7].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(9)").css({'left':posiciones[8].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(10)").css({'left':posiciones[9].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(11)").css({'left':posiciones[10].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(12)").css({'left':posiciones[11].left});
                    $("thead tr :nth-child(13)").css({'left':posiciones[12].left});
                    
                    console.log("anclado");
                    console.log(posiciones);
                    console.log($("thead tr :nth-child(1)").position());
                    
                }
                 
                console.log('tbody tr');
            }
            $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
            $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
            init();
        });
    };
    
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").fixMe();
    });
```

The real problem is when I set in thead the position left. For example:

```
$("thead tr :nth-child(1)").css({'left':posiciones[0].left});
```

the result of `posiciones[0].left` is 11 but it doesn´t set in  `$("thead tr :nth-child(1)")`

Comment: the first image is before scroll the thead isnt fixed and the the second image is fixed thead

Comment: this post isn't clear enough, images are useless, code too, no live example. Please show some effort or you'll be downvoted by community :/

Comment: okay i will edit

Comment: i edit the post